# Geoserver : add extra style (SLD) with Curl

Tags: geoserver, sld, linux, curl

In my **geoserver** I have a layer with a default style (SLD) and i want to **add another style to this layer with Curl**.

I tried command below with `<style></style>` instead of  `<defaultStyle></defaultStyle>` but without success :

```
curl -u admin:pass -XPUT -H 'Content-type: text/xml' -d '<layer><style><name>sld_name</name><workspace>workspace_name</workspace></style></layer>' http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/workspace_name:layer_name
```

Unfortunately I don't have found help in geoserver cookbook : http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/examples/curl.html.

Anybody know the answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally find the solution :

First, to add an extra style additionnal to the defaut style you have to use `<styles>` (and not `<style>`):

```
curl -u admin:pass -XPUT -H 'Content-type: text/xml' -d '<layer><styles><name>sld_name</name><workspace>workspace_name</workspace></styles></layer>' http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/workspace_name:layer_name
```

Second,you can't use this command x times if you want to add more than one extra style.  You have to use only one command with several `<names>` each time you add a style, here is an example :

```
curl -u admin:pass -XPUT -H 'Content-type: text/xml' -d '<layer><styles><name>Extra_sldname1</name><name>Extra_sldname2</name><name>Extra_sldname3</name><workspace>workspace_name</workspace></styles></layer>' http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/workspace_name:layer_name
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation to add extra additional styles

Answer (score 2):

You can also use -XPOST to add new availableStyle to your layer:

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<styles><name>yourstylename</name></style></styles>"
    http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/workspace_name:layer_name/styles
```

For example:

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<style><name>giant_polygon</name></style>"
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/topp:states/styles
```

This adds the Style "giant polygon" to your topp:states-Layer as an additional available Style.

Notice: if your style is bound to a specific workspace there seems to be a bug (style not found although i used the workspace tags...) but if the style is not assigned to a specific workspace this code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I the geoserver cookbok there are two curl examples about think that in the curl examples there are two about styles.

- [Creating a layer style](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/examples/curl.html#creating-a-layer-style)
- [Changing a layer style](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/examples/curl.html#changing-a-layer-style)

If you already have the style uploaded in geoserver to change the style of the layer:

```
curl -v -u admin:pass -XPUT -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<layer><defaultStyle> <name>sld_name</name></defaultStyle></layer>"  http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/acme:roads
```

The workspace tag that you are using in the XML is only useful when the style is only valid for a given workspace and is not global.

Comment: I appreciate the answer but it does not solve my question. I said that I already used <defaultStyle> for a default style, and now I want to add new additional styles. Thanks anyway :)